# Cassandra SizeTieredCompaction tombstone

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I've got an append only Cassandra table where every entry has a ttl. Using SizeTieredCompaction the table seems to grow unbounded. Is there a way to ensure that sstables are checked for tombstoned columns more often?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean for "the table seems to grow unbounded". Do you have problems with tombstones or with the space used by the table? Can you post your `nodetool cfstats`? Are you using snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

Tombstones will be effectively deleted after the [grace period](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html) (search for **gc_grace_seconds**) expires and a compaction occurs. You should check your YAML configuration for the parameter value (default is 864000 seconds, 10 days) and change it to something suitable for your needs. Beware that lowering this value has its own drawbacks e.g. row "resurrecting" if a node is down for more than the grace period.

Check the [datastax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html) about deletes in Cassandra.

Comment: gc_grace_seconds is 86400 (1 day), my ttl is set to 10 days. It's been > 20 days and still growing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have high loads of input data and do not modify it, you may better use [DateTieredCompactionStrategy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html#compactSubprop__compactionSubpropertiesDTCS) as it will be more efficient processing and removing the tombstones.

Comment: Unfortunately DateTiered did not work for me. I am selecting a rage of data and with date tiered the number of sstables examined per query is much larger than with size tiered compaction